# Hive external catalog error when pyspark is ran using oozie workflow

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The error is :
“   Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':”

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines.

Comment: That wrapper message is pretty useless. But somewhere in the stack trace below, you will find something about the root cause, probably in a _"caused by"_ entry. If you can't make any sense of the stack trace, then find someone with minimal experience in Java programming...